# HTML List Element

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have two List in a HTML document. Both List contains different data.

My acquirement is, If user select item in one list, then the same item should get added to another list in the same location.

**For example.**

```
list 1  - Hi, Hello       
list 2  - Thanks, Welcome
```

Suppose user select `"Hi"` in List1 then in List2 `"Thanks"` get replaced with `"Hi"` that is on the same position `list2[0]` .

I have read on internate that we can achieve this by using java script, But I didn't get any solution yet.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: i think you can go for jquery to do this. But please post your code.

Comment: What you want is to swap list items on the same index on user click?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say our markup is as follows:

```
<div>
  <ul id='list-1'>
    <li>Hi</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul id='list-2'>
    <li>Thanks,</li>
    <li>Welcome</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And we have the following javascript:

First, we select the two list elements:

```
var listOne = document.getElementById('list-1')
   ,listTwo = document.getElementById('list-2');
```

Then, we look in the children of these elements for the list items:

```
var listOneItems = listOne.getElementsByTagName('li') //returns an array
   ,listTwoItems = listTwo.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Next we set the action to perform when we click on the list items from the first list:

```
for(var i=0; i<listOneItems.length; i++){
 /*we use swap.call so that the function is in the context of this
   list item*/
 listOneItems[i].onclick = swap.call(listOneItems[i], i);   
}
```

Now we need to define the `swap` function:

```
/*this function returns the listener for the element, using a closure
  to bind the correct elements*/
function swap(i){
  var elem = this;
  return function(){
    listTwoItems[i].innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;  
  }
}
```

You can see it running [here](https://tinker.io/b45e0/1)